# Missing packages in xubuntu 19.04

Tags: xubuntu

I was shocked and puzzled  when I realized there are many packages are missing in xubuntu 19.04 such as qrfcview, and many others.
Those are not available regardless of which package manager is used, GUI or cli.At this point I am starting to lose confidence I once had with ubuntu.Please elaborate.

Comment: What sort of an answer do you expect? `qrfcview` is available only for LTS releases: 16.04 and 18.04. This is a wrong place to ask why.

Comment: thank you sir.Ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

The list of other distros *not* carrying `qrfcview` may help you hold on to your confidence in Ubuntu: https://repology.org/project/qrfcview/versions

In particular, if Debian drops a package, Ubuntu, which is based on Debian, will follow suit.